# RegEx Phrase Between Article (a/an/the) and Number (1-4 digits)

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have tried dozens of permutations of regex to solve this issue, but I have not been met with any luck.

I need to iterate through dozens of files, pulling specific phrases between "the/a/an" and a number with possible digits from 1-4, ignoring punctuation such as {}()[].

**Examples**

> The quick brown fox {15} jumps over the lazy dog [20] in a certain way 4
>   that is definitely not appropriate for all of the viewers (0012).

*Should return:*

> the quick brown fox 15
>
> the lazy dog 20
>
> a certain way 4
>
> the viewers 0012

Eliminating the punctuation isn't a problem: `sed 's/[][{}()]//g'`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -ioP "(a|an|the).*?\d{1,4}" files
```

The `-o` will print only matched text and each match on its own line.  `-P` is used for the reluctant quantifier and also makes the regex extended automatically.  You can of course pipe this output to `sed` as you have suggested above.

Comment: I'd rather use something like `\b(?:a|an|the)\b[^\d.]+\d{1,4}\b`.

Comment: The client is on OSX, so unfortunately the -P option is not available. This and @Qtax got me on the right path to: `grep -iEo "\b(?:a|an|the)\b[^\d.]+\d{1,4}\b"`

Answer (score 1):

In GNU awk you can split your input into records that end in numbers that are optionally surrounded by punctuation:

```
$ cat file
The quick brown fox {15} jumps over the lazy dog [20] in a certain way 4 that is definitely not appropriate for all of the viewers (0012).


$ gawk -v RS='[[:punct:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:punct:]]*' 'RT{print $0 RT}' file
The quick brown fox {15}
 jumps over the lazy dog [20]
 in a certain way 4
 that is definitely not appropriate for all of the viewers (0012).
```

Then all you need to do is print the parts of the record and the Record Terminator that you want:

```
$ gawk -v RS='[[:punct:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:punct:]]*' 'RT{print gensub(/.*\y(the|a|an)\y/,"\\1","") gensub(/[[:punct:]]/,"","g",RT)}' file
The quick brown fox 15
the lazy dog 20
a certain way 4
the viewers 0012
```

I just noticed that in your example you are converting your output to all lower case. Just throw a `$0=tolower($0)` in before the print to do that (also solves the problem of making the `the|a|an` comparison case-insensitive):

```
$ gawk -v RS='[[:punct:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:punct:]]*' 'RT{$0=tolower($0); print gensub(/.*\y(the|a|an)\y/,"\\1","") gensub(/[[:punct:]]/,"","g",RT)}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation! I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash and an exercise in the use of regular expressions:

```
while read line ; do
  line=" $line"                                 # add leading space as word boundary

  while [ -n "$line" ] ; do
    [[ "$line" =~ [[:space:]]((an|a|the|An|A|The)([[:space:]]+[^[:digit:]]+)([[:digit:]]{1,4}))(.+$) ]]

    match="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    match=${match//[()\[\]\{\}]/}               # remove parentheses
    [ -n "$match" ] && echo "'$match'"          # print if not empty

    line="${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"                   # the postmatch
  done
done < "$infile"
```

The output:

```
'The quick brown fox 15'
'the lazy dog 20'
'a certain way 4'
'the viewers 0012'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\b(the|an|a)\b/I!d;s//\n&/;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/\{([0-9]{1,4})\}|\(([0-9]{1,4})\)|\[([0-9]{1,4})\]|\b([0-9]{1,4})\b/\1\2\3\4\n/;P;D' file
```